# Angular UI modal with Bootstrap 4

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 3 modal works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLy7gk3f/4/

But Bootstrap 4 modal doesn't:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLy7gk3f/3/

The code is identical:

```
$scope.click = function() {
  $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "modal.html",
    controller: "modal",
    scope: $scope
  });
}
```

How can I get AngularUI modals to work with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: To add some background.. Angular UI Bootstrap simply isn't designed to be used with Bootstrap 4 ([click](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#bootstrap-requirements)). Support is being actively worked on in the NG2 version of the module ([click](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4234#issuecomment-225735134)).

Comment: @Ankh thanks, I've seen that. But some people on that thread say it's possible.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think it's just a case of adding the `.in` classes, specifically:

```
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLy7gk3f/5/

Or you could modify Bootstrap 4 to use the `show` class:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4234#issuecomment-285303515

Comment: I know I should avoid this, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I got solution by using below css

```
.modal.fade.in {
   opacity: 1;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
   transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
 }
.modal-header{
   display: block;
}
.modal-content{
   border-radius: 1.3rem !important;
}
```

/* Modal CSS Fix for Bootstrap 4*/