# Getting error $(...).modal is not a function in angularjs after upgraded bootstrap 3.3.6 to 4.0.0

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

After upgrading the bootstrap in my application from 3.3.6 to 4 I started getting error error $(...).modal is not a function, which(modal) was previously working fine. Error

```
angular.js:14700 TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
at ReviewQueueController.js?V=1.2:122
at angular.js:20440
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:6362)
at angular.js:6642
```

I am using angular js. when there is a success, error or any info I use modal. I have tried to replicate the issue with fiddle.

I have just started working  on angular so i am not sure how to fix.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15913/)

In many post i researched it was suggested to make changes to css

```
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
   -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
 }

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
 }
```

Also many link suggested to use noconflict like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586306/bootstrap-modal-is-not-a-function). I am not sure how no conflict will work with angularjs

please suggest what i can do to fix the issue

Comment: Can you post the full Error message you are getting ?

Comment: @sgiant please check the edit

Comment: Are your loading your Jquery  and Angular scripts BEFORE bootstrap ?

Comment: @sgiant yes I am. 1st jquery-{version}.js  2. angular js  3. bootstrap.js 4. bootstrap css 5. font awesome in bundle config. In html page1.jquery-ui.css     2.  jquery-1.12.4.js  3. query-ui.js

Comment: Alright how about placing the jquery-1.12.4.js just before bootstrap.js working ?

Comment: @sgiant  Nope, not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158903/discussion-between-dotnetbeginner-and-sgiant).

Comment: You need to include **popper.js** as well for **v4**, see [Getting Started Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/). Your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15916/) updated and working.

Comment: @vanburen you are my hero. is there a particular order in bundle config I  should follow

Comment: Yes, as far as the **Bootstrap Dependencies** go it's **jQuery**, then **PopperJS**, then **BootstrapJS**: you can refer to the [JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) section of the Getting Started.

Answer (score 0):

One solution mentioned in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog/issues/280) us to put this in your html:

```
<!-- Enable bootstrap 4 theme -->
<script>window.__theme = 'bs4';</script>
```

Also you might need to disable `ViewEncapsulation` in `app.component.ts`.

See "Disable CSS Encapsulation" [here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components) for how to do it.

**UPDATE**:

It seems that in your fiddle you're missing the jQuery script file. I added that in yours and now it works:

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/adel_mehrban/qxvg5bbb/)

Comment: i am using angular 1 . the article is for 2 and above

Comment: In that case this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690497/angular-ui-modal-with-bootstrap-4

Comment: I have already implemented that . I have also mentioned that in the question. Its not working

Comment: Could you please update your code with your import statements included? @DotNetBeginner

Comment: I am sorry someone downvoted you. let me fix that for you. all my code is in the fiddle exactly how i used it. fiddle link is in my question. I dont think there is import in angularjs. I am not so sure though  as in am very new to angular

Comment: Maybe the word import has confused you. That means your script tags which brings in js and css files into your app